# How can I modify default Jackson mapper that is used in swagger-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

`swagger-maven-plugin` uses Jackson to get information about DTO properties.
I have my own Jackson module (that extends `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule`) - how can I inject it into swagger lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Swagger extension and customize default mapper there:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.ext.AbstractSwaggerExtension;
import io.swagger.util.Json;

public class MyExtension extends AbstractSwaggerExtension {

    public MyExtension() {
        final ObjectMapper swaggerMapper = Json.mapper();
        swaggerMapper.registerModule(...);
    }

}
```

In `pom.xml` modify your `swagger-maven-plugin` configuration:

```
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <swaggerExtensions>
                           <swaggerExtension>
                             com.example.MyExtension
                           </swaggerExtensions>
                        </swaggerExtensions>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
```